# How do you make someone admin using discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried using this:

await name.Permissions.administrator()
but it didn't work any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Sean! You can't apply admin permissions to a user directly, but you can apply the permission to a role and give it to the user via [`user.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly give users permissions. Create a role with the `Administrator` permission, and then take a look at [user.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)